# Can Visual Studio 2022 (or ReSharper) show a list or tree of all references to a member sorted by order of execution?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, resharper

I'm rewriting code in a class that changes private state across many different private methods and it's difficult to follow what value each member of the class will end up having.

Assignments are mostly independent of their previous value and each other, so the state of many members is ultimately determined by whatever assignment is called last. They're all Booleans.

This is an example (in VB but the same applies for C#) of how the simplest case looks, without any branching or second-order methods with multiple references. Assume the method `SetVisibilities` is the entry point:

```vbnet
Dim isAVisible As Boolean
Dim isBVisible As Boolean
Dim isCVisible As Boolean

Private Sub SetVisibilities()
    ChangeVisibilitiesFirst()
    ChangeVisibilitiesSecond()
    ' This is the last change for C but is the earliest reference in the file (by line number)
    isCVisible = False
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeVisibilitiesSecond()
    isAVisible = False
    isBVisible = True
    isCVisible = True
End Sub

' This gets called first but is defined later in the file
Private Sub ChangeVisibilitiesFirst()
    isAVisible = True
    isBVisible = False
    isCVisible = True
End Sub
```

I would like to **safely** turn all the state changes for each member into something like this at first, before further simplifying each visibility evaluation:

```vbnet
Private Sub SetVisibilities()
    isAVisible = GetVisibilityForA
    isBVisible = GetVisibilityForB
    isCVisible = GetVisibilityForC
End Sub

Private Function GetVisibilityForA() As Boolean
    Dim response As Boolean
    response = True ' From: ChangeVisibilitiesFirst()
    response = False ' From: ChangeVisibilitiesSecond()
    Return response
End Function

Private Function GetVisibilityForB() As Boolean
    Dim response As Boolean
    response = False ' From: ChangeVisibilitiesFirst()
    response = True ' From: ChangeVisibilitiesSecond()
    Return response
End Function

Private Function GetVisibilityForC() As Boolean
    Dim response As Boolean
    response = False ' From: ChangeVisibilitiesFirst()
    response = True ' From: ChangeVisibilitiesSecond()
    response = False ' From: SetVisibilities()
    Return response
End Function
```

My manual approach has been to start at the entry point (`SetVisibilities`), then go depth-first into each method call and over each line of code until I find an assignment, then append that assignment to a bespoke new method for that specific member. If there is some branching involved, I append that too.

So far I've used Visual Studio 2022's *Find All References* and *View Call Hierarchy*, the first of which lists all references in the order they're found in the file, and while the call hierarchy is close, it is difficult to parse as it is represented in a tree that often looks like this:

```
- isCVisible
  - ChangeVisibilitiesSecond(), calls isCVisible on line 15
    - SetVisibilities(), calls ChangeVisibilitiesSecond() on line 7
  - SetVisibilities(), calls isCVisible on line 5
  - ChangeVisibilitiesFirst(), calls isCVisible on line 6
    - SetVisibilities(), calls ChangeVisibilitiesFirst() on line 5
```

While what I would prefer to see is something like this:

```
- SetVisibilities()
  - ChangeVisibilitiesFirst()
    - calls isCVisible on line 22
  - ChangeVisibilitiesSecond()
    - calls isCVisible on line 15
  - calls isCVisible on line 9
```

Comment: I'm also willing to try out any other tool, editor, extension or IDE with the capability to do this analysis.

Comment: You may want to look at tools that can generate a [UML Sequence diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) from code.

Comment: @Jonathan That would work! I'm trying to find one that works with Visual Basic, thanks! I'll edit this comment if I find one, Otherwise I'm just gonna follow the manual depth-first reference search

Comment: I would try re-writing the code so that it is less convoluted and reliant on the order you need to run the methods. Most tools probably work better with C# rather than Visual Studio. ReSharper does offer the 'Incoming Calls' and 'Outgoing Calls' inspections if that is helpful to you at all.

Comment: @Piers Yes, rewriting the code in this class is the goal here, towards which a tool like what I described or a sequence diagram would be a great help to ensure I'm not changing the current behavior.

Comment: I am assuming there are no unit tests then? :)

Comment: You are assuming correctly :)

Comment: StyleCop is an open source static code analysis tool that checks C# code for compliance with StyleCop's recommended coding style and a subset of Microsoft's .NET Framework Design Guide. This seems to be helpful for better understanding the flow of the code and how the state of different variables changes over time